# I want to download all the links on all the pages of a website, the number of pages is very very large

Tags: java

I tested a lot of code inside the internet but all of them just extract the first and second page and it's done,It does not matter to me what language the code is Java, Linux or Python, it is only important that the links of each page are downloaded in order and I can download all the links, the number of pages is several million.

Below are some Java code that I tested but did not solve my problem.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

            for (String link : findLinks("https://google.com")) {
                System.out.println(link);
            }

        }

        private static Set<String> findLinks(String url) throws IOException {

            Set<String> links = new HashSet<>();

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("query", "Java")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(3000)
                    .get();

            Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element element : elements) {
                links.add(element.attr("href"));
            }

            return links;

        }

    }
```

---

\The second code:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

            for (String link : findLinks("https://google.com")) {
                System.out.println(link);
            }

        }

        private static Set<String> findLinks(String url) throws IOException {

            Set<String> links = new HashSet<>();

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("query", "Java")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                    .cookie("auth", "token")
                    .timeout(300000)
                    .get();

            Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element element : elements) {
                links.add(element.attr("href"));
            }

            return links;

        }

    }
```

---

\code 3:

public class Main {

```
private static Set<String> findLinks(String url) throws IOException {


    Set<String> links = new HashSet<>();

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
            .data("query", "Java")
            .userAgent("Mozilla")
            .cookie("auth", "token")
            .timeout(3000)
            .get();

    Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        links.add(element.attr("href"));
    }
    return links;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String link : findLinks("https://google.com ")) {
        System.out.println(link);
    }
}
```

}

These few codes work for other sites but only download one or more pages for the site.

Comment: So you parse one page of a URL, do no recursion on the links from that page and wonder why the other pages aren't read. I strongly suggest a read on how recursion works, and also why this would be a bad thing to do with limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires more resources to be executed in a reasonable time.

1. Use multithreading in implementation
2. Make this service horizontally replicated microservice